# Format Dictionary from Array json Xcode Objective-c

Tags: arrays, json, xcode, dictionary

I really don´t know if this is a duplicate post, but I really did not know how to find what I was searching.
I have a Data from a json, this data is formatted in this way:

```
{
Age = (
"15",
"23",
"44"
),
Name = (
"Jack",
"Mark",
"Steve"
),
City = (
"New York",
"Los Angeles",
"Miami"
);
}
```

I need the data on a Dictionary style, like this:

```
{
Age = 15;
Name = Jack;
City = New York;
},
{
Age = 23;
Name = Mark;
City = Los Angeles;
},
{
Age = 44;
Name = Steve;
City = Miami;
};
```

I used this code to create a NSDictionary from the json Data:

```
NSArray *jsonResponse = [responseObject objectForKey:@"Age"];
NSMutableDictionary *allKeys = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int i = 0; i < [jsonResponse count]; ++i)
{
  NSArray *jsonAge = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"Age"]objectAtIndex:i];
  NSArray *jsonName = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"Name"]objectAtIndex:i];
  NSArray *jsonCity = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"City"]objectAtIndex:i];

  [allKeys  setObject:jsonAge forKey:@"Age"];
  [allKeys  setObject:jsonName forKey:@"Name"];
  [allKeys  setObject:jsonCity forKey:@"City"];
}
```

And I got this result as I expected:

```
   (
    {
    Age = 15;
    Name = Jack;
    City = New York;
    }
   )
```

the problem is, I need all data consecutive, and this offer to me segmented in a simple group.
How could I get a whole groups in one like this?

```
{
Age = 15;
Name = Jack;
City = New York;
},
{
Age = 23;
Name = Mark;
City = Los Angeles;
},
{
Age = 44;
Name = Steve;
City = Miami;
};
```

Some advice will be useful thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to create a model class and set values after you parse the JSON object. The model class would simplify how you manage/modify your data elsewhere in the code.

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *age;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *city;
@end
```

Then, you can parse the data and store them in an array of `Person` objects.

```
NSArray *ageArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"Age"];
NSArray *nameArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"Name"];
NSArray *cityArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"City"];

NSMutableArray *personArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int i = 0; i < ageArray.count; i++) {

  Person *person = [Person new];
  person.age = [ageArray objectAtIndex: i];
  person.name = (i < nameArray.count) ? [nameArray objectAtIndex: i] : nil;
  person.city = (i < cityArray.count) ? [cityArray objectAtIndex: i] : nil;

  [personArray addObject: person];
}
```

*Note: If the JSON server response could be modified to represent multiple `Person` object rather than an array of individual properties, it should be updated.*

Comment: Well look nice, but now I have an object, I´m not sure about how to convert to NSDictionary to extract the keys..  any suggestion?

Comment: Ok, i got what you mean, I didn't realize that my code works with a class but I need to feed that class with the json but is not properly formatted.

Comment: If you need a dictionary, you can always have a method that returns the dictionary representation of the Person object. Any reason you cannot use the Person object's properties instead of a dictionary?

Comment: Well I have a filter, then all data incoming have to go through that filter and then return and feed the class, so i can´t use the object because is not filtered. And I´m not quite sure about how to send Person object to the filter.